# JAXB / Jackson handling arrays of long

Tags: json, jaxb, jersey, jackson

I'm currently writing a Jersey REST interface. I'm have this code which I'm trying to create the following JSON response and a list of long is been generated a array of string (Using Jaxb and Jackson)

The code looks like  :

```
@XmlElement(name = "visitorProfiles", required = false)
private List<Long> visitorProfiles;
```

The JSON reponse looks like

```
{
   "visitorProfiles":["45"]
}
```

And I correct JSON response should be

```
{
   "visitorProfiles":[45]
}
```

This is what I'm using for the JSON configuration

```
context = new JSONJAXBContext(JSONConfiguration.natural().rootUnwrapping(true).build(),                 JerseyResources.getJaxbClasses());
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried to reproduce the case with no success, I can't see any reason for this to happen unless the natural context wasn't apply correctly for that class